# Cant apt-get remove or apt-get install | fopen permission denied

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi

So out of no where I was unable to SSH into my headless linux box.

So I hooked up a screen and started tooling with it.

My server is still fully functional and the box seems in tact. I just wouldn't let me SSH in.

So I tried follow a few online tutorials on adding my IP to the SSH allow file but nothing seemed to work.

I kept getting

> "Network Connect: Connection Refused"

when attempting to SSH in with putty.

So I decided to nuke the iptables and do

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge iptables
```

which resulted in a failure.

Something like this

> "processing tables for mandb " "fopen permission denied"

So I tried doing

sudo apt-get install iptables

which it said the same fopen error.

End result is my server is up and running but I have no ssh capabilities into my box. On that note though I do still have an active samba connection. Take that for what its worth.

Comment: funky errors like that always make me check that the disk isn't 100% full, which can lead to all sorts of strange behavior. Have you checked that (-- can you)?

Comment: No idea if I am reading this right so I will post a photo

Comment: looks good (Use% is less than 100). that's not the issue.

Comment: Did you try to just stop iptables? `/etc/init.d/iptables stop`

Comment: @RickHanlonII command not found. Guessing because the last thing I ran was the remove

Answer (score 11):

The fopen permission denied thing when doing apt-get or dpkg, is very often a sign that your manpages cache at `/var/cache/man` is owned by `root:root` instead of `man:root`. Try changing this with

```
   chown -R man:root /var/cache/man
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions below and the problem was solved. I hope it works for you.

```
sudo apt autoremove
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```